# SSL Certificate with many Subject Alternative Names, but one is not recognised

Tags: ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

I have installed a certificate in my web server (Apache 2.4/Centos 6) which defines 4 entries in the Subject Alternative Name. When I run a `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout` I get:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
DNS:site1.example.com,
DNS:www.site1.example.com, 
DNS:sub.site1.example.com, 
DNS:site2.example.com
```

The certificate works properly for `https://site1.example.com`. However, when I visit `https://sub.site1.example.com` I get a SSL error. When I click on "certificate details" in the browser, I only get a list of the other 3 alternative names, and this one's missing. Any hints as to what's going on? Tested with latest Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: From your description there should be no problem. Thus I think this will be impossible to resolve unless you provide the URL in question so one could see what's really going on.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Unfortunately it's a client's site so for now I can't share this information.

Comment: It might be simply another certificate you get. Try to add -servername to s_client so that you actually get the certificate using SNI, like the browser does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the server configuration. It kept using an older certificate rather than the new one.